# Make a new array form multidimensional array based on search conditions

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a multidimensional array. I want to search values(username IE jon) and count total "YES" for a specific username.

IE As per below array Andew is repeated three times Index 1,3,4  and its value is "YES" So Andrew's total "YES" count value = 3

Jon is repeated two times but its value is "NO" so it's value = 0

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jon
            [1] => NO
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Andew
            [1] => NO
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Walid
            [1] => YES
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Andew
            [1] => YES
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Andew
            [1] => YES
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jon
            [1] => NO
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Andew
            [1] => YES
        )

)
```

I want to make the user as key and value = count the total number of "Yes".

## OUTPUT

```
Array
(
john => 0,
Andew => 3
Walid => 1
)
```

Anyone, please suggest a possible solution?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Look into `array_reduce`.

Comment: @Jeto I have tried different functions and spent 4 hours but didn't get a solution I am stuck. Would you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Please share the closest one, and point out where you're stuck.

Comment: I've added an answer below. You should edit your question with what you've tried, instead of posting it in a comment, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick solution. Would you please upvote the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$stats = array_reduce($array, static function ($stats, $entry) {
  $stats[$entry[0]] = ($stats[$entry[0]] ?? 0) + ($entry[1] === 'YES' ? 1 : 0);
  return $stats;
});
```

This builds up a `$stats` array, sets its initial value to 0 for each person and increments it by 1 whenever a `YES` is found.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/NmZ7G**

Comment: I want to change in an array format. I just set up demo https://3v4l.org/6WNKE
I added an output format on the demo. Would you please check it and help me?

Comment: @Rigal Please make another question for it, it's a bit unclear what you want as a result here.

Comment: I asked a question and got an answer but I still need help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124427/group-by-array-using-multiple-values-and-sum-of-array-based-on-group-values-in-l/60124500?noredirect=1#comment106340623_60124500

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the count of 'YES', then the below will output a count.

```
$count_array = [];

foreach($array as $values){

    if(!isset($count_array[$values[0]])){

        $count_array[$values[0]] = 0;
     } 

    if($values[1] === 'YES'){

       $count_array[$values[0]] ++; 
    }       
}

print_r($count_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

(Not that different from @Jeto's array_reduce.)

A simple foreach:

```
<?php

$data =
[
    ['Brian', 'YES'],
    ['Brian', 'YES'],
    ['Charles', 'NO'],
    ['Charles', 'YES'],
    ['Nicola', 'NO']
];

foreach($data as list($name, $yes_no))
    $yes_counts[$name] = ($yes_counts[$name] ?? 0) + (int) ($yes_no === 'YES');

var_export($yes_counts);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'Brian' => 2,
    'Charles' => 1,
    'Nicola' => 0,
  )
```