# Group by array using multiple values and sum of array based on group values in loop and sorting array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to group array values and find total (sum of array value-based of the group by value) and then sort array based on total. I want to group by users by fund type ("Private, VC, Others") and the sum of total fund ("last value")

I have set up a demo link here.

https://3v4l.org/6WNKE

```
<?php

$data = [
  [
    'Jon',
    'NO',
    "",
    "Private",
    120
  ],
  [
    'Andew',
    'NO',
    "",
    "VC",
    150
  ],
  [
    'Walid',
    'YES',
    "",
    "Other",
    160
  ],

  [
    'Andew',
    'YES',
    "",
    "VC",
    150
  ],
  [
    'Andew',
    'YES',
    "",
    "VC",
    180
  ],

  [
    'Jon',
    'NO',
    "",
    "Other",
    150
  ],

  [
    'Andew',
    'YES',
    "",
    "Other",
    600
  ]
];

$arr = array();
foreach ($data  as $key => $item) {
      $arr[$item[0]][$key] =   $item['4'];
}

var_dump($arr);
```

I want below output

Group by ("Private, VC, Others") so value format like [sum of the private, sum of VC, a sum of Others ]

```
Array
(
    [Jon] => [120,110,0]
    [Andew] => [0,480,600]
    [Walid] => [0,0,160]
)
```

And then I want to sort array based on the total sum

```
Array
(
 [Andew] => [0,480,600]
 [Jon] => [120,110,0]
 [Walid] => [0,0,160]
)
```

Anyone please suggest possible solution to fic this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the result of a database query, this could almost certainly have been done more efficiently in that query. However, you can get the results you want in 3 stages:

1. group input data by person and type

```
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($data  as $key => $item) {
        $arr[$item[0]][$item[3]] = ($arr[$item[0]][$item[3]] ?? 0) + $item[4];
    }
```

2. fill in the missing values for each person

```
    foreach (array_unique(array_column($data, 3)) as $type) {
        foreach ($arr as &$person) {
            if (!isset($person[$type])) $person[$type] = 0;
        }
    }
```

3. Sort the array

```
    uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
        return $b['Private'] + $b['Other'] + $b['VC'] - ($a['Private'] + $a['Other'] + $a['VC']);
    });
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Array
(
    [Andew] => Array
        (
            [VC] => 480
            [Other] => 600
            [Private] => 0
        )
    [Jon] => Array
        (
            [Private] => 120
            [Other] => 150
            [VC] => 0
        )
    [Walid] => Array
        (
            [Other] => 160
            [Private] => 0
            [VC] => 0
        )
)
```

[Demo on3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/8kJMN)

Note I've left the keys of the inner array as associative as that seems more useful. If you would prefer numeric keys, you would need to sort each internal array so the keys were in the same order, and then take `array_values` of each entry:

```
$key_rank = array('Private' => 0, 'VC' => 1, 'Other' => 2);
foreach ($arr as &$person) {
    uksort($person, function ($a, $b) use ($key_rank) {
        return $key_rank[$a] - $key_rank[$b];
    });
    $person = array_values($person);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Andew] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 480
            [2] => 600
        )    
    [Jon] => Array
        (
            [0] => 120
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 150
        )    
    [Walid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 160
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GDlnaC)

To get the results in the form of an array with the name and values together, replace the last piece of code with this:

```
$key_rank = array('Private' => 0, 'VC' => 1, 'Other' => 2);
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $name => &$person) {
    uksort($person, function ($a, $b) use ($key_rank) {
        return $key_rank[$a] - $key_rank[$b];
    });
    $result[] = array_merge(array($name), array_values($person));
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Andew
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 480
            [3] => 600
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jon
            [1] => 120
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 150
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Walid
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 160
        )
)

[Demo on 3v4l.org][3]
```

Comment: @Rigal sorry I accidentally changed my sort. See my edit

Comment: @Rigal I've just made another edit to give numeric keys for the internal arrays if that's your preference

Comment: Thnak you so much for your quick help. I  want object intesd of every single array. IE  ['Andew',0, 480, 600].

Comment: @Rigal my output is **exactly** what you asked for in your question.

Comment: Yes but I want  to convert in object to display chart so I need ['Andew',0, 480, 600],['john',120,0,150],['Walid',0,0,160] .Would you please suggest me to convest in same object format?

Comment: @Rigal please make sure you ask for what you really want in the beginning. Anyway, see my edit, that does what you have asked for.

Comment: yes nick . Please help me to make  ['Andew',0, 480, 600],['john',120,0,150],['Walid',0,0,160] format .I mention in question about output "Array
(
 [Andew] => [0,480,600]
 [Jon] => [120,110,0]
 [Walid] => [0,0,160]
)" Thanks

Comment: your solution contains the wrong data in the last array.

Comment: @Rigal sorry - not sure how that happened but the `&` in `foreach ($arr as $name => &$person) {` accidentally got deleted between the 2nd and 3rd blocks of code. Please see my last edit which does have the correct code and data.